# passing excel table name in vba sub procedure argument

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel VBA sub procedure and I want to pass names of excel tables in the workbook to the arguments of this sub.

For example:

```
Sub Copyandfind()

SourceTableColumnCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count
SourceTableRowCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count
DestRowIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Count


i = 1
r = 0

Do While r < SourceTableRowCount

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

        Do While i <= SourceTableColumnCount

                ColumnName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange(i).Value
                On Error Resume Next
                DestColumnIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").Range.Find(ColumnName, MatchCase:= _
                True, SearchFormat:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).column
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                        'In case column name in source table is not found in destination table
                    Else
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange(DestRowIndex + 1, _
                        DestColumnIndex).Value = _
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(r + 1, i).Value
                    End If
                i = i + 1
        Loop

    r = r + 1
    i = 1
    DestRowIndex = DestRowIndex + 1
Loop
MsgBox ("Total records saved: " & SourceTableRowCount)

End Sub
```

I need to replace all table1 and table2 to be passed as arguments to use this procedure with different tables by just passing table names.

Thanks..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Where's the problem to pass the ActiveWorkbook to your sub?

Comment: So if you pass the name of the table "as a string" ... what happens ?  Seems `ListObjects` is expecting a string, so you just need to pass the string name ? (ie not the actual table object ..) ??

Comment: @Mat'sMug:
Yes the procedure will work with list objects only
I'm actually not an expert in VBA, I don't know how to specify in the signature?

Comment: @PeterSchneider,
Please check on my update I will post the full code

Comment: @Ditto
Please check on my update I will post the full code

Comment: `CopyAndFind(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal destTableName As String)`

Comment: @RubberDuck:
Thanks a lot...
Same idea for worksheet and workbook to be passed like this?

Comment: Yeah, but I would actually encourage you to refactor your code so that you're passing `ListObject`s and `Worksheet`s instead of strings.

Comment: @RubberDuck:
Can you provide 1 example and I'll do the research. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here. I didn't test it.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Set sourceTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim destTable As ListObject
    Set destTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")

    Copyandfind

End Sub

Sub Test2()

    Copyandfind ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")

End Sub


Sub Copyandfind(ByVal sourceTable As ListObject, ByVal destTable As ListObject)

    SourceTableColumnCount = sourceTable.Range.Columns.Count
    SourceTableRowCount = sourceTable.ListRows.Count
    DestRowIndex = destTable.ListRows.Count


    i = 1
    r = 0

    Do While r < SourceTableRowCount

        destTable.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

            Do While i <= SourceTableColumnCount

                    ColumnName = sourceTable.HeaderRowRange(i).Value
                    On Error Resume Next
                    DestColumnIndex = destTable.Range.Find(ColumnName, MatchCase:= _
                    True, SearchFormat:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                            'In case column name in source table is not found in destination table
                        Else
                            destTable.DataBodyRange(DestRowIndex + 1, DestColumnIndex).Value = sourceTable.DataBodyRange(r + 1, i).Value
                        End If
                    i = i + 1
            Loop

        r = r + 1
        i = 1
        DestRowIndex = DestRowIndex + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox ("Total records saved: " & SourceTableRowCount)

End Sub
```

Comment: awesome.
What I don't get is why initializing listObjects in new sub?

Comment: Because you have to call it from *somewhere*. You can't run parameterized procedures without passing them parameters.

Comment: Worked..This is how I called the sub:

Sub Save()

Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Set sourceTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim destTable As ListObject
    Set destTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")


Call Copyandfind(sourceTable, destTable)

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I would request ranges as inputs. The macro would start out with looking for an intersect of the range and a listobject in the worksheet along the lines of this macro.

```
Sub dfg(rng1 As Range)
Dim lo1 As ListObject, ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject
Set ws = rng1.Worksheet

For Each lo1 In ws.ListObjects
    If Intersect(lo1.Range, rng1).Cells.Count > 0 Then Set lo = lo1
Next
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
More clear, more concise:

```
Function DefineTable(str1 As String)
Dim lo As ListObject
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lo In Worksheet.ListObjects
        If lo.Name = str1 Then Set DefineTable = lo
    Next
Next
End Function
Sub ert()
Dim str1 As String, lo As ListObject
str1 = "Táblázat1"
Set lo = DefineTable(str1)
lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

The DefineTable will find your name and spit out the listobject.

**EDIT2**
Fresher than ever before:

```
Function DefineTable(str1 As String, Optional wb1 As Workbook)
Dim lo As ListObject, wb As Workbook

If wb1 Is Nothing Then
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Else
        Set wb = wb1
End If

For Each Worksheet In wb.Worksheets
    For Each lo In Worksheet.ListObjects
        If lo.Name = str1 Then Set DefineTable = lo
    Next
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks,
I'm actually not very much an expert in VBA. I'm still learning.
I didn't get what this should this do.

Comment: The first one would look for and intersect of the table's range and your defined range. If there is an intersect, it would define the listobject as the output.

Comment: As the listobject is part of the worksheet, the second looks at every listobject in every worksheet of the active workbook. If its name matches your string, then it returns the table as a listobject.